# Get consecutive letters, translate each letter to a number, and sum numbers in group

Tags: php, arrays, sum, mapping, cpu-word

Let's say I have these two related arrays:

```
$letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
$replace = [1, 5, 10, 15, 20];
```

And a string of letters separated by spaces.

```
$text = "abd cde dee ae d";
```

I want to convert consecutive letters to their respective numbers, sum the numbers, then replace the original letters with the total.

Using `str_replace()` isn't right because the values are compressed as a string before I can sum them.

```
$re = str_replace($letters, $replace, $text);
echo $re;  //this output:
   
1515 101520 152020 120 15
```

I actually want to sum the above numbers for each "word" and the result should be:

```
21 45 55 21 15
```

What I tried:

```
$resultArray = explode(" ", $re); 

echo array_sum($resultArray).'<br />';
```

It incorrectly outputs:

```
255190
```

EDIT:

My actual data contains arabic multibyte characters.

```
$letters = array('ا', 'ب','ج','د' ) ;
$replace = array(1, 5, 10, 15 ) ;
$text = "جا باب جب";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the string into an array and use [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php).

```
array_sum(explode(' ', $re));
```

**Edit**

Sorry, misunderstood:

```
$letters = array('a','b','c', 'd', 'e');

$replace = array( 1,  5,  10, 15 , 20);

$text = "abd cde dee ae d" ;

$new_array = explode(' ', $text);

$sum_array = array();

foreach ($new_array as $string)
{

  $nums = str_split($string);

  foreach ($nums as &$num)
  {
    $num = str_replace($letters, $replace, $num);
  }

  $sum_array[] = array_sum($nums);

}

echo implode(' ', $sum_array);
```

Comment: edited my answer look what it output . it output this `255190`

Comment: this outputs as an array not as i wished.

Comment: OK, I've changed to `echo` it as space-separated numbers.

Comment: Can you show me an example with Arabic letters in the question?

Comment: You probably need to enable `mbstring`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

Comment: ok i fixed it here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php thanks again, the problem was the split

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the letters with numbers I would suggest just looking up the letters in the replace array one at a time:

**EDIT**

```
<?php
    $text = "abd cde dee ae d";
    $replace = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 5, 'c' => 10, 'd' => 15, 'e' => 20);
    $letters = str_split($text);
    $sums = array(0);

    foreach ($letters as $letter) {
        // Add a new element to the sum array.
        if ($letter == ' ') {
            $sums[] = 0;
        } else {
            $sums[count($sums) - 1] += $replace[$letter];
        }
    }

    echo implode(" ", $sums);
?>
```

Here is a working example:
http://codepad.org/Cw71zuKD

Comment: I apologise, I meant str_split not explode - and $sums[-1] is meant to be the last index not the -1th, let me fix that....

Comment: thanks , but michael was first who solve it , i appreciate your fix also , +1

Answer (score 0):

Because the summed results after translating sequences of letters is meant to be used as the replacement text in the output string, I find `preg_replace_callback()` to be a fitting tool to encapsulate and deliver the required logic.

1. Isolate a substring of letters
2. Split each respective set of letters into an array of individual characters
3. Perform the necessary translation to integer values
4. Sum the array of numbers
5. Replace the original substring with the summed value
6. Repeat until all substrings are replaced

Code: ([Demo](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/448262732377238c17024e7c2e32bf25/))

```
$letters = ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e'];
$replace = [1,  5,  10, 15 , 20];
$text = "abd cde dee ae d";

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/[a-e]+/',
         fn($m) => array_sum(
             str_replace(
                 $letters,
                 $replace,
                 str_split($m[0])
             )
         ),
         $text
     );
```

Output:

```
21 45 55 21 15
```

---

For multibyte processing: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/USoRt))

```
$letters = array('ا', 'ب','ج','د' ) ;
$replace = array(1, 5, 10, 15 ) ;
$text = "جا باب جب";

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/\S+/u',
         fn($m) => array_sum(
             str_replace(
                 $letters,
                 $replace,
                 mb_str_split($m[0])
             )
         ),
         $text
     );
```

Output;

```
11 11 15
```