# Sum array numbers

Tags: php, sum

This my code:

```
   $letters = array('a','b','c', 'd', 'e');
   $replace = array( 1,  5,  10, 15 , 20);
   $text = "abd cde dee ae d" ;
   $res = array_sum(str_split(str_replace($letters, $replace, $text))) ;

  echo $res ; // this output:   40
```

It should output : `157`

This means when i replace letters by numbers then i counted them by `array_sum`

Whats wrong with it ?

EDIT:

```
    $letters = array('ا', 'ب','ج','د' ) ;
    $replace = array(1, 5, 10, 15 ) ;
    $text = "جا باب جب";
```

Comment: You asked it yesterday : D and I guess this is the behaviour you asked it to have!

Comment: its not same , yesterday was sum in array but this sum of total

Comment: here if you want see if its same  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722903/sum-numbers-in-a-replaced-string-by-numbers

Comment: @PolishPrince its not duplicated i know what i ask

Comment: why should be 157? can you prove that?

Comment: @Akam if you count all letters by its equivalent number you find 157

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, what's happening here is that each character in the string is being split, i.e `15`, the replacement for `d` will be split as `1` and `5`. Separately. Instead, try this:

```
$replace = array( '1 ',  '5 ',  '10 ', '15 ' , '20 ');
$letters = array('a','b','c', 'd', 'e');
$text = "abd cde dee ae d" ;
$res = array_sum(explode(' ', str_replace($letters, $replace, $text))) ;
echo $res ;
```

What's happening here is that `explode()` splits the string at the given delimiter (here, the SPACE character). See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

by arabic letters try this

```
   function mb_str_split( $string ) {
     return preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $string );
     } 
   $res = array_sum(str_replace($letters, $replace,mb_str_split( $text))) ;
```

Comment: works good :) thanks , my fault is the split :)

Comment: Use `mb_split()` for multi-byte character-sets like Arabic, instead of `explode()`. Just replace `explode()` with `mb_split()`. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php)

Comment: i edited your answer if you dare and i fixed it thanks

Comment: Haha, simultaneously suggested a similar approach :)

Comment: thanks :) , i dont know why downvote on me :)

Answer (score 1):

`str_split()` splits by letter but you apply if **after** you replaced the letters with numbers. That means, for example "20" will be split into "2" and "0".

You might want to split first, then replace the letters with help of `array_map()`

Comment: thanks and much appreciated your answer

Comment: can you explain your method by array_map ?